# AVAudioPlayer not playing on some devices

Tags: ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

My code is working perfectly on simulators, on iPad-4 and on iPhone 6+, all running iOS 9.0.2.

However, and I know that's a weird claim, on my iPad Air 2 it *looks like* it's working, but actually nothing is heard. Also reproduced on other devices like another iPhone 6+ and another iPhone 6 running iOS 8.4. I have create a demo project (link below) so that others can try their own device.

I'm doing this:

1. Initializing an `NSURL *url` with a path under `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]`:
   `/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0ACADB94-886E-4C7E-A327-3FFF0E54CEF9/My App.app/sndEfcts/!snap.mp3`
2. Assigning a new object into an ivar:

   ```
   audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err];
   ```
3. Test url in debugger - good! (notice that the space became %20. I also verified that the file exists):

   ```
   (lldb) po audioPlayer.url
   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0ACADB94-886E-4C7E-A327-3FFF0E54CEF9/My%20App.app/sndEfcts/!snap.mp3`
   ```
4. Play if created ok:

   ```
   if (audioPlayer) {
       audioPlayer.delegate = self;
       [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
       __unused BOOL playOk = [audioPlayer play];
   }
   ```
5. Delegate of finish is activated:
   `- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag`

   ... and flag is saying YES! - but nothing is heard :(

So everything appears to be ok, and still no sound is heard (although other sounds of other apps do work ok)

Does anyone have an idea for the cause of such behavior?

EDIT

I have create a [simple project](http://wikisend.com/download/917000/AudioTest.zip) to demonstrate. It is happening on various devices, even on 8.4. On simulators it is always working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution.

On problematic devices, "mute" was on, affecting *some* of the sounds in the device. To prevent this, call this somewhere on beginning of your app:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
```

This will cause the audio to be treated as playback and thus not be muted by the mute option.

I have learned that users typically don't know where to find the mute on/off control. On iPad Air 2: raise the lower pane from bottom and press the speaker icon.